# How to select a specific checkbox with dynamic id's with Cypress

Tags: angular, checkbox, dynamic, selector, cypress

I'm trying to select a checkbox but there isn't a single identifier I can figure out that will let me select a specific checkbox.

HTML:
[image]

Note, this is checkbox two of three on the page.  The ID will change depending on my flow, so I can't use the ID to grab this.  While it currently shows up as 4 it could be much higher by the time my test gets to it.

This is what I used to find all checkbox's on the current page: cy.get('.mat-checkbox-input')

However, I can't use .eq() to select the second option as it throws an error that the element is detached from the DOM.

Is there any good way to grab a list of checkboxes or selectors in general, and then iterate through them to use only the one I want?  In this scenario, i know the checkbox is always the second checkbox.

Everything in this image is identical to the other two checkboxes with the exception of the ID. I guess this is how Angular tends to work. Of course as noted earlier, the ID will change as the page loads, or things are interacted with making it impossible to tell what the number is.

All also have the same label code:
[image]

EDIT 2: I decided to try a {force:true}, and it works.  My previous edits i deleted as it was another element causing a new problem.  The first response works if I added (force:true).  Thanks for the help, and i hope this helps others with similar issues.  I'll mark the first response as the correct answer.

```
cy.get('input[type="checkbox"]')
          .each(($elem, index) => {
            if(index === 1) {
                cy.wrap($elem).click({force:true});
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate through elements with the function each:

```
cy.get('input[type="checkbox"]')
  .each(($elem, index) => {
    if (index === 1) {
      cy.wrap($elem).click();
    }
  })
```

See documentation about "each" [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each.html#DOM-Elements)

Comment: Wow this is nice, however, it throws the "Cypress requires elements be attached in the DOM to interact with them".  I did verify in the console that it found the exact item I needed, but then it fails with the .wrap() command.

It won't let me add the image, so i'll edit it into the OP.